# [Android]How to show a view in layout B on top when it is moving towards edge of both layout B and A?

Tags: android, layout, imageview, touch-event

My case is: 
I have 2 Layout A and B, A is on top and B is at bottom, like

```
----------------
-              -
-LinearLayout A-
-              -
---------------  -
-                -
-RelativeLayout B-
-                -
---------------  -
```

And I create an **ImageView C** in RelativeLayout B and set an on touch so that C can move around inside B. But when C is moving at the **edge of A and B**, the ImageView C is cut by A and **only the lower part** of C is showing on B.

My question is: how can I show also the **upper part** of C when it is moving at the edge of A and B?

Answer (score 0):

One way you can do this is to create a third layout C that is full screen, superimposed over the two you describe above.  Then, do your dragging about in C.

```
<FrameLayout -- this is your top level layout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent" >

  <LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout ... /> -- A
    <LinearLayout ... /> -- B
  </LinearLayout>

  <View  -- this is the full screen view
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@null" >  -- null background makes it transparent
  </View>

</FrameLayout>
```